# Extract the count of positive and negative values from an array

Tags: python, list, count

I need to work with an array to make some computations. I have the following data:

```
x = [[81, 68, 71, 71, 67, -72], [79, 77, 88, 88, 59, -71], [67, 71, 68, 68, 85, -66]]
```

and I would need to play with the data and extract from each column the number of positive and negative values so the output should be like:

```
positive_value = [3,3,3,3,0]
negative_vaue = [0,0,0,0,3]
```

I gave it a try using a `for` loop with no success and with Numpy as well, but I do not really know how to use it.

What is the best way to get that result?

Comment: why positive_value = [3,3,3,3,0] ?

Comment: @keyvanvafaee: I think the OP want's to count row wise. So the first column has three positive values, the second three as well, etc.

Comment: How do you want to count `0`?

Comment: "I gave it a try using for loop with no success" You should show us what you tried. You probably got that downvote because your question doesn't contain your own attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Convert it into array, transpose it. Now your columns have become row, and you can simply count how many of the of them is positive, rest of them become your negative counts

Comment: @keyvanvafaee Its counting column wise positive_values only counts the positive ones, thats why its three for most cases

Comment: Thx for your answer, I need it in order to do calculate weigthted average based on the number of positive and negative value

Comment: Also, will your sublists always be of the same length as each other? IOW, is `x` a 2D rectangular matrix, or is it possible for some rows to be longer or shorter than other rows?

Comment: Yes it is a 2D mAtrix,  same length each time, no longer no shorter

Comment: Excellent. But you **still** haven't told us what you want to do with zeros in the data! If it's impossible for zeros to occur, you need to tell us that.

Comment: Sorry Zeros are not possible to occurs

Comment: I would use len() on np.where(condition) where condition is a tuple; x>=0 for positive values, etc

Comment: You have 6 columns, so the result should be:
positive_value = [3,3,3,3,3,0]; 
negative_vaue = [0,0,0,0,0,3]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably the most elegant way is to convert it to a [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array first, then perform a condition `>= 0` on it, and then calculate the `sum(..)` over the first axis:

```
import numpy as np

np.sum(np.array(x) >= 0, axis=0)
```

This then yields:

```
>>> np.sum(np.array(x) >= 0, axis=0)
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0])
```

So by using `np.array(x) >= 0`, we obtain a 2d-array of booleans:

```
>>> np.array(X) >= 0
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Since `True` counts as one, and `False` as zero, by calculing the sum per column, we thus count the number of positive numbers.

In case you want to count *strictly* positive numbers (so only larger than zero), you should omit the `=` in `>=`:

```
>>> np.sum(np.array(x) > 0, axis=0)
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0])
```

Answer (score 5):

without any library

```
pos = [ sum(y>=0 for y in x)  for x in zip(*mylist) ]
neg = [ len(mylist)-x for x in pos]
print(pos, neg)
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/926751)

Comment: I'd probably do `len(mylist)` outside the list comp; OTOH, `len` is very fast, so it would only make a tiny difference to the speed unless `mylist` is huge.

Comment: @PM2Ring In real code, I do too. Let's leave something for homework :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use count_nonzero function ,for this you may need to modify your array

```
>>> np.count_nonzero(np.eye(4))  #identity matrix              
4            
>>> np.count_nonzero([[0,1,7,0,0],[3,0,0,2,19]])   
5           
>>> np.count_nonzero([[0,1,7,0,0],[3,0,0,2,19]], axis=0)         
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])         
>>> np.count_nonzero([[0,1,7,0,0],[3,0,0,2,19]], axis=1)        
array([2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = [[81, 68, 71, 71, 67, -72], [79, 77, 88, 88, 59, -71], [67, 71, 68, 68, 85, -66]]
>>> zipped = list(zip(*x))
>>> for items in zipped:
    pos = len(list(filter(lambda i: i > 0, items)))
    neg = len(list(filter(lambda i: i < 0, items)))
    positive_values.append(pos)
    negative_values.append(neg)


>>> positive_values
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0]
>>> negative_values
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the output that the OP is aiming for.

Comment: Yes It is not what I am looking for .. I am doing it in order to calculate weighted average ..

Comment: @Ben2pop You still haven't told us what you want to do with zero items in the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
twoD = [[4,3,2,-1],[3,2,1,-1],[1,1,-1,-2],[-1,-1,-2,-3]]
pos = neg = 0
for row in twoD:
   for col in row:
      if col < 0:
         neg += 1
      else:
         pos += 1
print('Number of positive integers are', pos, 'Number of negative integers are', neg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the answer from [splash58](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4804629/splash58) above works, and beautifully written:

```
matrix_2d = [[81, 68, 71, 71, 67, 72], [79, 77, 88, 88, 59, -71], [67, 71, 68, 68, 85, -66]]

pos = [sum(y >= 0 for y in x)  for x in zip(*matrix_2d)]
neg = [len(matrix_2d) - x for x in pos]

print('Positive counts by columns: ', pos)
print('Nagetive counts by columns: ', neg)
```

However, if you want to look deeper in the working of algorithms, here is a simpler version, although lengthier and more verbose:

```
matrix_2d = [[81, 68, 71, 71, 67, 72], [79, 77, 88, 88, 59, -71], [67, 71, 68, 68, 85, -66]]

matrix_rows = len(matrix_2d)
matrix_cols = len(matrix_2d[0])

positive_counts = [0] * matrix_cols
negative_counts = [0] * matrix_cols

for col_idx in range(matrix_cols):
  for row_idx in range(matrix_rows):
    if matrix_2d[row_idx][col_idx] < 0:
      negative_counts[col_idx] += 1
    else:
      positive_counts[col_idx] += 1


print('Positive counts by columns: ', positive_counts)
print('Nagetive counts by columns: ', negative_counts)
```

I change the input of the **matrix_2d[0, 5]**, so the expected result is:

```
Positive counts by columns:  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
Nagetive counts by columns:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```